# How to format Postgres Datetime to Month Day, Year - Day of Week

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres DateTime field. The Data looks like this "**2021-05-13**"

How can I format the output in a query as   "**May 13, 2021 - Thursday**'

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

```
select to_char('2021-05-13'::timestamp, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY - Day');

 to_char          
--------------------------
 May 13, 2021 - Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is in a text field you must cast it to date

```
select '2020-10-20'::date
```

then if you need to format it you can use `to_char`

```
select to_char('2020-10-20'::date, 'Mon DD, YYYY - Day');
```

If the column is a date you do not need to add `::date`

Comment: FYI, `Mon` is three letter abbreviation. The month of May fits in this, but if the OP is actually looking for full month you need to use `Month`.